# BTC-E API (Retrieve error)

Tags: api, error, btce

Is it normal to infrequently see errors retrieving trade/depth history by API from BTC-E? Or should I never see them.

I seem to be seeing at least one such error each day, I am running my script on an Amazon EC2.

Thanks,
Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most exchange APIs fail at times. Add a sleep-and-retry to your code.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. How long do you think the sleep should be/number of times to retry?

Comment: Depends on the exchange's request limit and how urgent the data is, you wouldn't want to abuse the API service. Personally I'd give it at least 10 seconds but it's up to you.